# Mnogosearch is skipping pages

Tags: search

I am using mnogosearch 3.3.7 for indexing a website that I am working on.  I am running into an issue where sometimes pages that the indexer should be able to find are not appearing in search results.

The indexer is being run in BLOB mode, and I can confirm both from verbose output from the indexer and from looking in the DB that the URL's that are missing from search are indeed being indexed.  Taking a look at the schema that mnogosearch uses and making a few educated guesses at its structure, I believe that indexed url's are kept in the url table, and those are cross referenced with entries in bdicti.  The interesting thing is that while it seems like most URL's that are in the url table have corresponding bdicti table entries, the URL's missing from search do not.  It might be a bum lead, but that's all I got.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the indexer -Eblob after the indexing process?